# When clicking another component in NavBar of app, path in URL fills but component doesn't open until I refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am working on a `NavBar` in my app that is meant to take me to other components in the application. One of these components is called the history page. I am learning how to use `react-router-dom`. I want it to be that when I click the link in the `Navbar`, it doesn't refresh the whole application. I just want it to render the component I am selecting on the screen.

Here's my component that handles the routing:

```
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar";
import HistoryPage from "./pages/HistoryPage";
import MainPage from "./pages/MainPage";
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  { path: "/", element: <MainPage /> },
  { path: "/history", element: <HistoryPage /> },
]);

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <NavBar />
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here's the NavBar component:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import HistoryPage from "../pages/HistoryPage";

function NavBar() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <nav className="nav">
        <Link to="/">HOME</Link>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/history">History</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default NavBar;
```

As of right now, when I click the history component in the navbar, it will update the URL to `"www.website/history"`, but it doesn't actually render on the screen unless I refresh the page. How do I get it to just open without having to refresh? I don't want to have the app refresh every time I switch to another component as another part of my app pulls a random item from a database. If it refreshes, it pulls a new item and I don't want that.

Here is the Main Page:

```
import React from "react";
// import Description from "./Description";
import Description from "../components/Description";
import ImageCarousel from "../components/ImageCarousel";
import GuessInput from "../components/GuessInput";
import { app } from "../firebaseConfig";
import useRandomObject, {
  useGetLocationsList,
  useGetLocationFromSearch,
} from "../components/firebaseUtiility";
import SearchBar from "../components/SearchBar";
import Hint from "../components/Hint";
import { useState } from "react";

function MainPage() {
  const [selectedLocation, setSelectedLocation] = useState("");
  const { randomObject } = useRandomObject();
  const { fullLocationList } = useGetLocationsList();
  const { randomFromLocation } = useGetLocationFromSearch(selectedLocation);

  function handleLocationSelect(location) {
    setSelectedLocation(location);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Description />
        <ImageCarousel object={randomFromLocation || randomObject} />
        <GuessInput object={randomFromLocation || randomObject} />
        <Hint object={randomFromLocation || randomObject} />
        <SearchBar
          placeholder="Search location..."
          locationsFromDatabase={fullLocationList}
          onLocationSelect={handleLocationSelect}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default MainPage;
```

The history page only displays a header, haven't added any functionality.

The random thing I pull from the database is randomObject, or randomFromLocation, but these two work more or less the same.

When I click History, click back to Home, there's a new randomObject. I want it to remain the same while navigating through these different components

Answer (score 0):

You are rendering the links in the navbar into a ***different*** router than the app routes are rendered into, so the actions dispatched and handled in one  router are not known in the other router.

To resolve the `Navbar` component should be rendered within the ***same*** router as the routes they are linking to. For this you can create a layout route that renders the `Navbar` and an `Outlet` for nested routes.

Example:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import HistoryPage from "../pages/HistoryPage";

function NavBar() {
  return (
    <nav className="nav">
      <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/history">History</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
}

export default NavBar;
```

```
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
  Outlet
} from "react-router-dom";
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar";
import HistoryPage from "./pages/HistoryPage";
import MainPage from "./pages/MainPage";

const AppLayout = () => (
  <>
    <NavBar />
    <div id="main-content">
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  </>
);

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <AppLayout />,
    children: [
      { path: "/", element: <MainPage /> },
      { path: "/history", element: <HistoryPage /> },
    ],
  },
]);

function App() {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works, but the only issue is that it refreshes when I click one of the links, and I do not want it to do that. Is there anyway to have it render the clicked component without it refreshing?

Comment: @JamesF Can you clarify what specifically you are clicking and what specifically is refreshing?

Comment: I am clicking the History link and the Home Link in the Navbar. 

On my home page, I render an array of photos that I store in a database. Each array of photos is stored in their own object in my database. I randomly pull one of these objects from the database and display it on the home screen. 

When I press the history link, then press the home link again, the object that is pulled (array of images) has been changed, and I am certain it is due to the application being refreshed.

Comment: I want it to be not have to refresh when I press on one of these link.

Take netflix for example.

When I am on the main page on Netflix and I navigate to the movies tab, then the TV shows tab, then the My List tab, it doesn't ever refresh. It just loads the component. I am wondering how that's done.

Thank you very much, by the way.

Comment: @JamesF If the app is on route path `"/"` then the `MainPage` component will be mounted. When you navigate to `"/history"` then `MainPage` will unmount. If you then navigate back to `"/"` then `MainPage` will mounted again, running any `useEffect` hooks that might be fetching data and setting any local state. This is just how React works. If you don't want to run logic each time `MainPage` mounts then move that logic somewhere higher up the ReactTree so it's run less often, `AppLayout` for example.

Comment: @JamesF Can you add the `MainPage` and `History` components to your post if you think it would make understanding what your code is "refreshing" clearer to readers here, e.g. me?

Comment: Hey @Drew Reese, I've gone ahead and added the MainPage. I think I will have to do what you said about moving the useEffects higher up the React Tree, I will just need to figure out how to do so effectively.

You won't see the useEffect in this code, but I use to get things like useRandomObject and useGetLocationFromSearch

Comment: @JamesF If you move those custom hook calls from `MainPage` into `AppLayout` you can pass their values down via the `Outlet` component's context provider and use the [useOutletContext](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-outlet-context) hook in `MainPage` to access.